# Debugging Nunit Tests inside VS2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I have written a bunch of unit tests inside VS2010 Express and tests being tests they sometimes fail. Since the express editions of VS don't allow plugins to run I can't simply spin up TestDriven.Net or an equivalent and debug the tests. To try and work around this I've converted my test assembly into a console app and made the main method look like this:

```
class CrappyHackToDebugUnitTestInVSExpress
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssemblyByName(
          @"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe",
          new [] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "/framework:4.0" });
  }
}
```

In theory I should be able to run this up, set break points in my test. *If* it worked it would be an acceptable work around, but I keep getting the following:

```
FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'C:\\Program Files\\NUnit 2.5.5\\bin\\net-2.0\\nunit-console.exe' 
or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

Now the file exists and when run manually nunit-console runs fine. What might be my problem?

Comment: Why don't You just attach to NUnit GUI runner?

Comment: You cannot do "attach to process" in Visual Studio Express.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I played with your concept and it appears the issue isn't directly from loading the file, but from dependencies.

I used the following modified code:

And the error was actually a failure to locate nunit.core.dll, which is in the /lib directory.

```
 try
        {
            String NUnitPath = @"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.7\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe";

            AssemblyName asmName = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(NUnitPath);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssemblyByName(asmName, new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "/framework:4.0" });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

(I like getting System.Reflection.AssemblyName because you can inspect and see that everything's in order verses the raw file path.)

A quick bulk copy (xcopy nunit.*.dll) into my test projects' debug directory and it ran just fine. (It should be trivial to discover the minimal dependencies required)

Tested in VC# 2010 Express with NUnit 2.5.7 (breakpoints work, but I didn't really play with any other options.)  Although I'm sure you could make a passable build option from it.

Cheers!

PS - First post here so I'm a bit untested as to getting the 'code' blocks formatted.  Sorry in advance..

Answer (score 7):

Basically you need to convert your assembly to Windows Forms app, add reference to the **nunit-gui-runner.dll** assembly and change your Main method to look like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
    }
```

here is another example:

```
...
using NUnit.Gui;

namespace __libs
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new string[] { @"C:\test\bin\Debug\test.exe" });
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to step into certain tests but is not very good for a red green cycle, so you will want to use this only when debugging and not in other circumstances.

Comment: If you ever get a runtime error in a new project, check if Main is running as a [STAThread]. If not the NUnit GUI cant load.

Comment: This is great. Our line reads like the following `NUnit.Gui.AppEntry.Main(new string[] { @"Test.exe", "/run" });`, to avoid hardcoding a path (NUnit will see it anyways), plus running it automatically when it loads.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to debug unit tests in VS C# express. Had a hard time getting it to work properly but then I found out about this project template. Works perfectly in C# Express!

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b8a7a8fa-9f5a-4b9b-8e8b-8839a4364f26?SRC=VSIDE

> C# Project Template
>
> Integrated tests with Visual Studio, including Visual C# Express
>   version
>
> Self contained NUnit console runner. Allow to write test fixtures and
>   test, running from Visual Studio simply by pressing F5 (support test
>   debugging), or Ctrl-F5 free run with results in console window. In
>   case of test failure indicate by beep sound.
>
> Contains essential NUnit modules to start test project. No external
>   dependencies. Simply create new project, using NUnit Test Application
>   template.