# How to add 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.UnitTesting' reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am a new to C#. I want to add 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.UnitTesting' reference to my project but could not find it in .Net tab. Any ideas on where I can find this or do I need to install anything else to see it in .Net tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which VS version you have?

In VS 2010 family, in my case Ultimate for example it is called `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` and living here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`.

If you have VS 2008 or 2010 express edition you still may use http://www.nunit.org/ fro unit testing.

By the way VS 2008 Architecture Edition also missing Unit Test functionality http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955869

Have a look this [Unit testing in Visual C# 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424229/unit-testing-in-visual-c-2010-express)

Comment: Thanks bigb. I am using VS 2008 Architecture edition. I navigated to same path under 'Microsoft Visual Studio 8' folder but I don't see mentioned dll. any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found dll on above path on different machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We've created a tool that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.

[image]

Regards...