# Debugging xUnit tests in Visual C# Express?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-c#-express-2010, xunit, xunit.net

I have written [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com) tests for my C# solution.

[Visual C# Express does not integrate with unit test tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424229/unit-testing-in-visual-c-sharp-2010-express), so people usually use external tools, and indeed I have used the external xUnit test runner so far.

But now I would like to debug a particular test within Visual C# Express, because this test crashes the xUnit test runner.

I am thinking of creating a dummy executable project that just references the unit tests project and calls the test.
Any smarter idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to upgrade to [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop), you can use the [xUnit.net runner for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099). Otherwise you might be able to attach to the test runner's process (**Debug** -> **Attach to process...**) and debug it that way.

Comment: I have switched to NUnit, so I can't try, but that like what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this functionality exists in the Express version, but you should be able to do `Tools -> Attach To Process`, then attach to the xunit test runner application (make sure it's running). Place a breakpoint in one of your tests, and when you Run the test(s) in the xUnit Test Runner, you should be able to debug like normal.